# Switch Java Button image back and forth?

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jbutton

I have a program that uses a switch which has the action event passed to it on button click:

```
public void buttonImageReveal(ActionEvent e){

    String temp = e.getActionCommand();

    switch(temp){

        case "1":
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setIcon(one);
        delay();
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setIcon(null);
        break;
```

Delay is just a call to a function with a 1 second wait:

```
 public void delay(){
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
        }
            catch(InterruptedException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

All that results is a wait and no image, the desired outcome is a flash of the image for a second.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the code up, the whole code, or just a piece, because there aren't closing brackets...

Comment: What do you mean by flash of an image? What exactly you want to achieve? You want image to keep flashing or you want your image to disappear for 1 second and show it again?

Comment: there I can't see any problem, for me work in all cases, please post a http://sscce.org/

Comment: Is the image variable correctly referenced, ie. does it point to the correct path of the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After setting the icon you are making the thread sleep so it can't paint the new icon. Immediately after sleep is over you set icon to null. So you will never see the icon painted.

You can try to change the icon using `javax.swing.Timer` periodically.

Comment: excelent catch +1, I'll delete my post

Comment: Ah yes, so obvious now you say it, so whats a good wait function to use that doesn't cause this?

Comment: @Eric you already got this answer from @AKJ: just use `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: I missed that, but I've gotten a bit further but still no joy:

        Timer gameTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

              repaint();
            }
          });
     
     String temp = e.getActionCommand();
     switch(temp){
         case "1":
          System.out.println("case1");          
          ((JButton)e.getSource()).setIcon(one);
          gameTimer.start();
          ((JButton)e.getSource()).setIcon(null);
          break;

Comment: @EricBanderhide Rather than calling repaint() in your timer's action performed try calling setIcon(null). In the switch, after setting the icon just start the timer. Idea is to reset the icon when the timer fires.